# Is 'negotiate down' the same as 'bargain down'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> “There were even times at the beginning where I was **negotiating down**
> the percentages of the Ether distribution that both myself and the
> other top-level founders would get, in order to be more egalitarian.
> That did make them upset.”

I wonder if 'negotiate down' has the same meaning as '[bargain down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bargain+down#:%7E:text=bargain%20(someone%20or%20something)%20down&text=To%20convince%20someone%20to%20accept%20a%20lower%20price%20for%20something.)' which means 'To agree to pay a lower price for something'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do mean the same thing and they can be used interchangeably. But "negotiate" is generally used in more formal/businesslike/high stakes situations. "Bargaining" or even "haggling" is more typically used when, for example, talking about trying to get a cheaper price in a shop/store/market.

Comment: Thank you very much.